# Concat files 1 & 2, 3 & 4, 5 & 6 (and so on) in a dir of 3000+ using command line

Tags: macos, command-line, concatenation, command, batch-processing

Recovered photos off my dad's digital camera card but the individual files themselves are useless. They seem to have been restored at JPEG marker points, so the info about the camera, exif info etc is in the first file (000001.jpg) and the actual photo data in a separate file (000002.jpg)

Having opened them in a HEX editor, and copy/pasted the contents of file 000001.jpg into the very start of file 000002.jpg then saved, file 000002.jpg is now 'correct' and can be opened with Preview/image apps.

I have a directory of 3200+ files I need to repeat this for!

I have used concat and similar commands before so not scared of the terminal, but I can't really get my head around how I'd phrase the command to step and repeat concating 000001 + 000002, 000003 + 000004, 000005 + 000006 and so on.

Any help much appreciated.

Edit: I am on a Mac, but have access to a PC. The answer supplied by Stephan involved moving the files onto a PC and running a batch cmd. It worked, my problem is solved.

Comment: Just to clarify, currently, based upon your [[tag:cmd]] tag, this is a Windows Command Prompt, i.e. cmd.exe, question. In Windows, there is no such built-in command or utility named `concat`. If this question is not intended for use in Windows, and cmd.exe, I would strongly advise that you [Edit] it accordingly. Please also note, that the current answer is a Windows Command Script, often referred to as a batch file, and since you haven't tagged your question for one of those, it does not answer it. We aren't a free code writing service, because we can't fix no code, this question is off topic.

Comment: Apologies, this is a Mac related command line query, hence the inclusion of the Preview app showing all correct files. Will edit accordingly.

Comment: Adding another clarification as people are getting hung up on Mac or PC specifics. I am a Mac user, so my first thought was to try a Mac solution. There was only one answer posted, and it involved a PC. I'm happy to do whatever to get the task completed. I will be clearer next question I ask (despite using SO a lot, I think this was my first question). Thanks again to Stephan for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%a in (1000001,2,1003201) do (
  set "low=%%a"
  set /a "high=%%a+1"
  ECHO debug: low=!low:~1!.jpg, high=!high:~1!.jpg  ; add a command to join them, like the following (UNTESTED!) command:
  ECHO copy /b !low:~1!.jpg + !high:~1!.jpg new_!low!.jpg
)
```

You mentioned "more than 3200", so adapt the last number accordingly. Fine for a "one-time" solution; if you plan to do it regularly, there are methods to count the files.

**NOTE:** this depends on the first part *always* having an odd number, and the second part is *always* "first plus one". A missing odd file should give an error message, a missing even file doesn't give an error, but the resulting file will only have the contents of the odd file.

Remove the `ECHO` with the `copy` command *after verifying it's correct*.
The `ECHO debug` line is just for troubleshooting, you can safely remove it.

And of course: always work with a copy of your data or have a valid backup.

Comment: @Compo: my answer is based on the tags (`cmd` at that time). I'll keep my answer anyway, because the logic remains valid, even when the code itself won't run on Mac without changes.

Comment: This is great! Thank you.

A small percentage of files didn't work, but I'm assuming that's because the marker data wasn't recovered fully, or the component n or n+1 file was missing.

Will mark as accepted answer. Cheers!

Comment: I'm very confused why you would accept this answer as resolving your question since it won't run on macOS. Your comment implies it solved your problem but that is impossible if the files are actually on a macOS system. I suspect that you really did mean that the files are on a Windows system. In which case this solution looks, at first glance, like it should work. @jake

Comment: @KurtisRader the files are not on a Windows system. It would be incredibly hard to make that mistake. As you probably know, JPGs can be transferred across from a Mac to a PC and having access to a PC, and only one solution posted here, I did the pragmatic thing and tried it out. 

It worked. So I gave credit to Stephan and marked the problem as answered.